# Oracle: unique index with check on a specific value

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have a simplified table with two columns (group, key).

A key must be unique within a group, but it also have to be unique compared to a 'reference' group.

So I created a unique index (group, key) for the first constraint, but is it possible to create a unique index for the second rule?
function based?

A small example, if the table contains (group, key) :

```
'reference', 'key1'
'group1',    'key2'
'group2',    'key2'
```

this insert should be rejected:

```
'group1',    'key1'
```

Thanks

Comment: Is 'reference' a single fixed value you always want to compare against?

Comment: yes, it is a hardcoded value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can fit that logic into a unique or check constraint. You may have to resort to using a trigger to enforce this:

```
create trigger trg_ref_grp_check
after insert or update on t42
declare
  l_cnt pls_integer;
begin
  select max(count(distinct case when group_id = 'reference' then 1 else 0 end))
  into l_cnt
  from t42
  group by key;

  if l_cnt > 1 then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Key defined for reference and group');
  end if;
end;
/
```

The `max(count(...))` will only return 2 if the same key is used for reference and one or more groups; the case statement within the count reduces each entry to 'reference' or 'non-reference', and counting distinct values of those will give you either 1 or 2 for each key - and if it gets 2, you have both reference and non-reference group values. The trigger then throws an exception if that happens:

```
insert into t42 (group_id, key) values ('reference', 'key1');
insert into t42 (group_id, key) values ('group1', 'key2');
insert into t42 (group_id, key) values ('group2', 'key2');

insert into t42 (group_id, key) values ('group1', 'key1');

SQL Error: ORA-20001: Key defined for reference and group
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.TRG_REF_GRP_CHECK", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCHEMA.TRG_REF_GRP_CHECK'

select * from t42;

GROUP_ID   KEY 
---------- -----
reference  key1 
group1     key2 
group2     key2
```

This will also prevent a reference entry being added for a key that is already used by any non-reference groups. You still need your unique constraint/key as well, of course.

---

As @sstan pointed out, because the trigger fires when the DML finishes and not when it is committed, two sessions could simultaneously insert conflicting entries and then both commit, without either seeing an error from the trigger.

A slightly more involved approach is to create a materialised view that calculates the counts of reference and non-reference entries, and have a check constraint on *that* which fires on commit:

```
-- drop trigger trg_ref_grp_check

create materialized view log on t42 with rowid;

create materialized view mv_ref_grp
refresh on commit
as
select key,
  count(case when group_id = 'reference' then 1 end) as ref_cnt,
  count(case when group_id != 'reference' then 1 end) as nonref_cnt
from t42
group by key;

alter table mv_ref_grp add constraint chk_ref_grp_cnt
  check (ref_cnt = 0 or nonref_cnt = 0);
```

You can't use `distinct` within the case, so the view is calculating total counts for both reference and non-reference appearances, and the constraint then checks that one of them is zero at commit time. It does mean you see the error slightly later:

```
insert into t42 (group_id, key) values ('group1', 'key1');

1 row inserted.
```

And that session can see (and use) the 'bad' entry:

```
select * from t42;

GROUP_ID   KEY 
---------- -----
reference  key1 
group1     key2 
group2     key2 
group1     key1
```

But when you commit an exception is thrown, and the bad entry no longer appears:

```
commit;

SQL Error: ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA.CHK_REF_GRP_CNT) violated
12008. 00000 -  "error in materialized view refresh path"

select * from t42;

GROUP_ID   KEY 
---------- -----
reference  key1 
group1     key2 
group2     key2
```

Comment: I like this answer.  Be aware however, that it is still possible to insert invalid values in concurrent situations.  For instance, if in tx 1 you do `insert into t42 (group_id, key) values ('reference', 'key1');`, and in tx 2 you do `insert into t42 (group_id, key) values ('group1', 'key1');`, and then you commit both transactions, both rows will get inserted without an error.  But given the unusual requirements, not sure if there is a better solution.

Comment: @sstan - yes, good point. A more robust solution might be having a refresh-on-commit materialised view but that might be excessive...

Comment: Well thank you for your solutions. In my case this is not for production environment, only for development, so it does not need to be that bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a check constraint :

```
CREATE TABLE <...>(
group <...>,
key   <...>,
CONSTRAINT <...> UNIQUE (group, key),
CONSTRAINT <...> CHECK  (group != 'group1' OR key != 'key1'))
```

Or insert the reference group in the table with a flag that says it's not "real".